# How to log distributed python processes across a machine farm

Tags: python, logging

Anyone have any experiences on this?

How would I unify logs for a distributed system with python because I dont know what's happening on remote machines.

I have been looking into python built-in logging but it seems to not have a good documentation for logging a distributed system.

Comment: On Linux, you can have Python log to rsyslog and configure rsyslog to log remotely to your computer

Comment: I have a Python distributed system with celery, so I have a custom logging.Handler that logs to the same broker used for tasks, and I have a consumer writing those messages to logfiles. If you also use celery, that works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) for Python 2.x:

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from
>   multiple threads in a single process is supported, logging to a single
>   file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no
>   standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple
>   processes in Python. If you need to log to a single file from multiple
>   processes, one way of doing this is to have all the processes log to a
>   SocketHandler, and have a separate process which implements a socket
>   server which reads from the socket and logs to file. (If you prefer,
>   you can dedicate one thread in one of the existing processes to
>   perform this function.) This section documents this approach in more
>   detail and includes a working socket receiver which can be used as a
>   starting point for you to adapt in your own applications.
>
> If you are using a recent version of Python which includes the
>   multiprocessing module, you could write your own handler which uses
>   the Lock class from this module to serialize access to the file from
>   your processes. The existing FileHandler and subclasses do not make
>   use of multiprocessing at present, though they may do so in the
>   future. Note that at present, the multiprocessing module does not
>   provide working lock functionality on all platforms (see
>   http://bugs.python.org/issue3770).